# How to remove all files from fine uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I am using fine uploader in dialog box to upload files and it is working fine,

The problem is, After uploading all files, I am closing dialog, When user opens same dialog again, uploaded files are already there, I want to remove those files after uploaded successfully all files.

Is there any way to remove all files in onAllComplete callback:

code:

```
var personalPhotosUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('personalContent-fine-uploader'),
        template: 'qq-template-personalContent-trigger',
        request: {
            endpoint: FoaUrl.AddPersonalContents,
            customHeaders: {
                "UserId": '@FaceOfArtz.Web.Models.UserIdentity.Id(User.Identity.Name)'
            }
        },
        callbacks: {
            onAllComplete: function (succ, fail) {
                if (fail.length == 0) {
                    EditPortfolioPhotos();
                    //qq(this.getItemByFileId(0)).remove();
                    $.each(succ, function (index, value) {
                        alert(value);
                        qq(personalPhotosUploader.getItemByFileId(value)).remove();
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        thumbnails: {
            placeholders: {
                waitingPath: '/source/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                notAvailablePath: '/source/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
            }
        },
        autoUpload: false,
        debug: true
    });
```

Comment: `qq(this.getItemByFileId(0)).remove(); // I want to remove all` what is `qq`? Your code is a little part of structure, and it s difficult to help you..

Comment: I changed my question, please look into it

Comment: look, you are realy think that someone can help you, if your problem is in `qq(personalPhotosUploader.getItemByFileId(value)).remove();` call? It doesn't work, you know that, and if you want get help, maybe you can show it or what are you waiting for?

Comment: I guess its for JavaScript support, " http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/qq.html, "
Selects an HTMLElement and returns a qq 'wrapped object.'

Comment: I am using qq, because on tutorial page they have defined it

Comment: @KevalPatel I've rolled-back your most recent edit, as it no longer matches up with your actual question.

Comment: No worries, I made changes because my question was containing information about my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "remove" any files from Fine Uploader. I'm not sure why you would want to do that. You *can* remove elements from the DOM though. If you'd like to remove a single element that represents a file, you can do this by looking up the associated element, given its ID, using [`getItemByFileId`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getItemByFileId) and then removing it using whatever method you prefer. If you'd like to remove all of these items, you have a few options. One involves calling the [`reset`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#reset) method on Fine Uploader's API. This is probably the easier approach, as others involve looping over all files and removing the associated elements in a loop.

Comment: Yes, Just what I needed. 
If possible then give answer for this link too... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500000/how-to-add-headers-at-runtime-in-fine-uploader